# Get-AzMlWebService command not returning anything while updating existing ML model

Tags: azure, machine-learning, deployment, azure-powershell

I have a machine learning trained model and a web service created and deployed in Azure Machine Learning studio (Classic). I have retrained the model with the new data through Batch Execution and the output trained model is stored as ilearner file in the Azure Blob storage. Now, I'm trying to update the previous web service with the new through Azure powershell as mentioned in the documentation. Its connected to the Azure account with the Connect-AzAccount cmdlet but its not giving any output for the Get-AzMlWebService cmdlet. I have also tried many command variations (with the experiment name and resource group name)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Try [`Get-AmlWebService`](https://github.com/hning86/azuremlps#get-amlwebservice) of the [classic module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/classic/powershell-module#classic).

Comment: Thank you so much Joy Wang. Its working !!! Yaaayy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`Get-AmlWebService`](https://github.com/hning86/azuremlps#get-amlwebservice) of the [classic module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/classic/powershell-module#classic).

```
# Get all classic Web Services in Workspace
$webServices = Get-AmlWebService
# Display them in table format
$webServices | Format-Table Id,Name,EndpointCount
# Get metadata of a specific classic Web Service with Id stored in $webSvcId
Get-AmlWebService -WebServiceId $webSvcId
```